# Why do I get an error that exceeds the maximum runtime when I use neo4jphp to manipulate the neo4j library in PHP?

Tags: php, neo4j, max-execution-timeout

I'm developing a website with thinkphp where I'm going to do an excel file to bulk import data into the neo4j library.Before adding data to the neo4j library, I need to check the correctness of the data and then create nodes into neo4j node by node.But when there are many nodes, PHP will quote "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 1200 seconds exceeded" error. I was wondering if I could disconnect PHP from the neo4j library and reconnect to avoid this error.

wampserver 3.1.5 php 5.5.12 thinkphp 3.2 neo4j 3.4 max_execution_time=1200

```
for($i=$startRow;$i<$dataNum;$i++){
    $row=$excelData[$i];
    $data=array();
    $realColNum=count($row);
    $colNum=$colNum<$realColNum?$colNum:$realColNum;

    for($j=0;$j<$colNum;$j++){
        $key=$keyList[$j];
        $value=trim($row[$j]);
        if ($value!="NULL"){
            $data[$key]=$value;
        }
    }

    if ((!empty($data['id']))&&(!empty($data['uuid']))){
        $nID =  neo4j_updateNode_import($sysid,$data);    //update node
    }else{
        $nID=neo4j_addNode("People",$data);    //add node
    }   
}
```

[13-Jul-2018 20:38:52 PRC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 1200 seconds exceeded in E:\wamp\www\ThinkPHP\Library\Vendor\Neo4j\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Curl.php on line 86